# How do I link multiple files without the use of a makefile?

Tags: c++, linker, terminal, g++

For example, I'm given *carModels.cpp*, *carModels.h*, *carType.in*, *manufacturers.h*, *manufacturers.o*, and lastly my own file *tester.cpp*.  How would I go about linking all of these using g++ in a Linux terminal?  Would I have to create any additional ".o" files?  I'm supposed to assume that the given files already work.  Multiple lines in terminal are fine, I just I want a clear understanding of it.  (I'm coming from a C++ IDE that I didn't really care for.)

Comment: maybe this would help http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html

Comment: Are you assuming that *your* file, `tester.cpp`, already works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile each source file to its own object file:

```
g++ -I . -c carModels.cpp -o carModels.o
g++ -I . -c tester.cpp -o tester.o
```

Now link all object files together:

```
g++ carModels.o tester.o manufacturers.o -o outputname
```

Consider adding more options like `-O3`, `-std=c++11`, `-Wall`, etc. as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two steps, first compile to *.o files,

```
 gcc -c your.cpp other.cpp .....
```

then link them

```
gcc -o you_out_put_name the_object_files.o ...
```

Comment: I received an error and I'm unsure what it is: tester.cpp: In function 'int main()': tester.cpp:37: error: request for member "part' in 'CarType::typCar)i', which is of non-class type 'CarType::typCar'

Comment: @Unfazed: Is that the single error? `carType.in` is a rather unusual filename, and that may be related. G++ doesn't know about it.

Comment: .in is just an input file, not included with the linking.

Comment: Found out the error I had was from one of the given files by my colleague.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In a single line, that would be just `g++ -o tester *.cpp  *.o`. GCC will sort everything out. In particular, the `*.h` files are referenced via `#include ""` statements in the `.cpp` files.